# Invalid inputs in a SR Latch & Enabled SR Latch

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, latch

Lets consider a SR Latch built with NOR gates. The invalid inputs are S=1, R=1. With enabled latch [gated latch], the invalid inputs are same, S=1, R=1.

Now, lets consider, NAND gates, in SR Latch, the invalid inputs are S=0, R=0. But in enabled SR latch, the invalid inputs are S=1, R=1 :

[image]

Why is this so? Is it because the latch getting inverted inputs, i.e. S'R' (as in the image)?

So, can I say, invalid inputs with SR Latch with NAND are:

1. S=1, R=1
2. If enabled, then S=0, R=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Lets consider a SR Latch built with NOR gates. The invalid inputs are S=1, R=1. With enabled latch [gated latch], the invalid inputs are same, S=1, R=1."

That is true only when the gating does not invert the signal (for instance two AND gates).

"Now, lets consider, NAND gates, in SR Latch, the invalid inputs are S=0, R=0. But in enabled SR latch, the invalid inputs are S=1, R=1"

Correct, because the gating inverts the S and R signals.

"So, can I say, invalid inputs with SR Latch with NAND are: S=1, R=1"

Correct

"If enabled, then S=0, R=0"

That is half-true. You should be able to formulate the fully-true answer by yourself.

Comment: So the correct way of phrasing would be - "If enabled & the signals are inverted then S=0, R=0" ?

Comment: I agree with that.

Answer (score 0):

Now, lets consider NAND gates implementation of ungated SR Latch, the invalid inputs are S' = 0, R' = 0. But in enabled SR latch, the invalid inputs are S=1, R=1.

This is because S' = 0 iff S = 1 and R' = 0 iff R = 1.